# Installing fonts --- what about the map file?

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I'm trying to install the Web-O-Mints fonts into Texlive on my linux box. I got the files from CTAN in `fonts/webomints`. The installation instructions were for a `teTeX-like` installation. The `texlive` directory structure is a little different but I, hopefully, put the `*.tfm`, `*.pfb` and `*.fd` files in their correct places under the `texlive/texmf-local` directory. But I'm unclear as to where the `webo.map` file should go and how to ensure that it is permanently available. I have a vague recollection that `updmap -sys` should be used for something but can't remember what or how (I do recall that if you use `updmap` at some point you shouldn't use `updmap -sys` later, and vice-versa). Also, how do I ensure that all the new files are noticed by LaTeX?

(In the past, say eight years ago, I managed to install several font families but they have all mysteriously vanished, somewhat like my memory!)

Comment: This is much much easier: https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/, webomints are included. Btw: the map files goes into a similar structure as in texmf-dist, getnonfree is just so much easier.

Comment: In case you want to do this for fonts not covered by `getnonfreefonts`, you can use this guide: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

Comment: If it is similar to Windows, you should have your webo.map in `texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/webomints/`. The font diles are mentioned in `psfonts.map` and `pdftex.map`.

Comment: @daleif Thanks to you I now have a whole new set of fonts, including webomints. I had spent some considerable time trying to get webomints installed and working but getting and using getnonfreefonts took a fraction of that time, plus getting all the other fonts as well. How about providing an answer based on your comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it is a lot easier to install webomints via the `getnonfreefonts` feature, see

https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Remember that once installed (super easy), `getnonfreefonts` has a help function to list the various options, which include listing the available fonts that can be installed via this tool.

---

(assuming texlive)

As for installing manually.

1. see the structure in `texmf-dist/fonts/` the structure is fairly straight forward. (map files often go into `fonts/map/dvips/` for some reason(?)

   Add the files in a similar structure, but under `texmf-local`.
2. Run `texhash` to update the filename database.
3. Probably a good idea to test of the system can find `webo.map`, test via `kpsewhich webo.map`, it should report the full path. If it reports something like `./webo.map` go to a different folder and test form there.
4. Activating the font:

   ```
   updmap --sys --enable Map webo.map
   ```
5. That should hopefully be it.